# Keep formatting while pasting to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: encoding, text-formatting, visual-studio-2012

I'm having trouble keeping special formatting while copying from Notepad++ to Visual Studio 2012.

I can't paste it here either, so I've made some images.
Notepad++
[image: This is how it looks in Notepad++]

Notepad
[image: This is the Notepad encoding]

The characters in question are special whitespaced values I need to save while copying the string to Visual Studio. How would I be able to do this? I've tried copying from Notepad++ to Notepad, from Notepad++ to Google Chrome and then to Visual Studio, I really tried a lot of things.

Comment: What happens when you try to paste them?

Comment: "special whitespaced values" You mean this is a UTF-8 encoded string?

Comment: @DaveRook The special characters just disappear..

Comment: @Ali I'm not sure what encoding it is, I'm not really good with those things...

Comment: If your copied string is UTF-8, try this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/688760/how-to-create-a-utf-8-string-literal-in-visual-c-2008

Comment: @FabianPas  What about if you *try* open VS, and under Tools, Options, Navigate to Text editor and turn off Auto-Detect UTF-8. Or navigate under Text Editor and select All languages and select Enable virtual space